# Passing base 64 in webapi gives error Request URL Too Long

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I am trying to post an image in webapi for my android client but when i am execute the code it shows me error as "Request URL Too Long". I tried with [from body] also. but got the same error.Can some one help me out please.

My action method is

```
 [HttpPost] public IHttpActionResult InsertWallPostFeeds([FromBody] string objwallfeed) 
 {
     WallFeedpost objwall = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<WallFeedpost>(objwallfeed);
 }
```

Below is my Postman request.

[image: Postman Request]

Comment: Perhaps you send the image data inside the URL instead of the body. `[FromBody]` does nothing if the data _is not in the body_. The reason is that, by specification, an URL can be 2048 characters long maximum.

Comment: This is how i am passing.. [HttpPost]
        public IHttpActionResult InsertWallPostFeeds([FromBody] string objwallfeed)
        {}

Comment: I can see that there is a JSON in your message body, but also look at the URL. You append the JSONized object to the URL and that's what causes the error. You only need to add it to the body.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your postman request I can see that you are passing the json as string through url. You have to pass it through body.
The Postman Request looks similar to below screehshot

[image: Postman Request]

Comment: I am not using javascript the service is for Android user. [HttpPost]
        public IHttpActionResult InsertWallPostFeeds([FromBody] string objwallfeed)
        {
            WallFeedpost objwall = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<WallFeedpost>(objwallfeed);
           ...some code}

Comment: Could you please check android code?. It seems from android the data is being passed through url. Your server side code looks good.

Comment: i am trying to test this in post man and getting the error..Url too long

Comment: Could you please attach a screenshot of Postman script window

Comment: <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<HTML>
    <HEAD>
        <TITLE>Request URL Too Long</TITLE>
        <META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" Content="text/html; charset=us-ascii">
    </HEAD>
    <BODY>
        <h2>Request URL Too Long</h2>
        <hr>
        <p>HTTP Error 414. The request URL is too long.</p>
    </BODY>
</HTML>

Comment: Please see the url, you are passing the json as query string. You have to pass it as json through body. You have to click on body tab next right to Authorization and Header tab, and remove the json string from key value

Comment: See the image [https://ibb.co/jt4GbQ](https://ibb.co/jt4GbQ) how it should look like